# Mobile PUSH SFMC - Images not coming on Android 13

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

Do we need to set up Rich media for Android too? Images are not coming for android 13 and Beyond

Comment: I have Android 13 and have no issue. The SDK simply downloads the image from the URL you provide. Image size, network speed, and network/vpn/device restrictions are the only thing that can impact image display.

Comment: For Android - No additional Development required like IOS for Rich media? currently, Android 12 is Working fine but for 13 it is not working.

Comment: Without any further information than you've provided: I have no clue. What version of the SDK? What version is on the device? Are you overriding notification handling? If so, did you include the require immutability flags? Probably best to open a support case. But, to answer your question in the comment, no, it just works.

Answer (score 1):

No additional code is required. This is a version of the SDK w/Android 13 support, the application is built for Android 13, and the device is running Android 13.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: We have installed SDK 7 instead 8, I think this is the problem and now we are trying to upgrade. I hope this will fix this.

Comment: SDK 7 works exactly the same, however, it does not have Android 13 support.